Same inner product with functions in $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ implies same functions in $H^1(\Omega)$?
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. It is true that if $u,v\in H^1(\Omega)$ and
$$(u,\phi)_{H^1(\Omega)}=(v,\phi)_{H^1(\Omega)},\ \forall\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$$
then $u=v$? Here I have denoted by $(\cdot,\cdot)$ the inner product and $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ the smooth functions with compact support in $\Omega$. I know that this statement its true when the inner product its in $L^2(\Omega)$ but I dont know if its true when the inner product its is in $H^1(\Omega)$.
Thanks for the help !

The claim is not true: take $\Omega=(0,1)$, $u(x)= \exp(x)$, $v=0$, $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.
Then
$$
(u,\phi)_{H^1} = \int_0^1 \exp(x) (\phi' + \phi) dx
=\int_0^1 \exp(x) (-\phi + \phi) dx + \exp(1)\phi(1)-\exp(0)\phi(0)=0,
$$
where I have used integration by parts.

The condition $(u,\phi)_{H^1}=0$ for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$
means $-\Delta u + u=0$ in $\Omega$. However, no boundary conditions are imposed on $u$ yet, so we are free to choose.
Then a similar construction works for general $\Omega$: Take $u$ as the weak solution of $-\Delta u+u=0$ in $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions $u=1$ on $\partial \Omega$.

Problem here is that $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$.
In that sense, the claim is only true if $H^1(\Omega)=H^1_0(\Omega)$.

That was a very nice answer. Thank you so much. So if I understood well, if we impose the boundary condition $u=v=0$ in $\partial\Omega$ then the equatility $u=v$ holds?

Yes, if the boundary is nice enough.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

@Shaun Honestly, I am not sure which kind of context should be added. The question concerns the most basic concepts in the study of Sobolev spaces. It is a natural question as similar claims appear everywhere in a standard course. I will include this question into my  set of  exercises for the course on Sobolev spaces.
